# Removing first line or row (header) and first column of multiple csv files

Tags: linux, batch-processing

I have thousands of csv files, I want to remove the first row (header) and first column. This is my code, but it to overwrite the original files with no content:

for j in *.csv; do    sed '1d' $j |    cut -d, -f 1 > "$j"; done

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> This is my code, but it to overwrite the original files with no
>   content

That is because the redirection of output `> "$j"` causes the file to be truncated to zero size before its contents have been read. To avoid this, a temporary output file can be used.
A minor error in the code is that you specified the column to be removed instead of the columns to be kept in the `cut` command.

Corrected code:

```
for j in *.csv; do sed 1d $j | cut -d, -f2- >new$j && mv new$j $j; done
```